# Adjacent component disappears when child route is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-component

We have this structure in our app (these are wrapped in some parent component):

```
<Announcement />
<Content />
```

Now in my `<Content />` component's `componentDidMount()`, I have a condition on whether to dispatch the action that displays `<Announcement />` or not as in:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(loggedIn) {
      this.props.showAnnouncement();
    }
}
```

`showAnnouncement()` is being mapped as props from the redux store. So far this is fine.

However, also in my `<Content />` component is a child modal box component that is shown via Router when a button is clicked. Let's say I am in `www.website.com/somePath`. When I click the button, the route will change to `www.website.com/somePath/modalLabel` and a modal overlay will appear above the page.

Now the problem is that after I click the button which triggers modal, the `<Announcement />` component disappears.

I suspect this is because the route changed (even if it's a child route).

Should I then do `this.props.showAnnouncement();` on another lifecycle method? I am not sure what's happening.

Comment: Yes you need to call the action this.props.showAnnouncement(); again because you are doing that in componentDidMount and this method gets called only once. So in button click call this action again this.props.showAnnouncement();

Comment: @Think-Twice Which lifecycle method do I call it again? Since it's the route itself that's being changed..

Comment: Perhaps in button click event handler function